# formatting data into a new structure javascript

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am working with D3 at the moment as an experiment, I recieve data from an API in a certain format, but I need to retructure that data into format that works with D3 below is an example of the data that I am receiving.

```
{
    "user_id": 3,
    "service_user": "Phillippa",
    "staff_name": "Abbey",
    "role": "A",
    "staff_id": 2,
    "status": "P",
    "workbase": "Workbase 1"
},
{
    "user_id": 60,
    "service_user": "Raymond",
    "staff_name": "Adam",
    "role": "D",
    "staff_id": 8,
    "status": "C",
    "workbase": "Workbase 2"
},
{
    "user_id": 63,
    "service_user": "Alison",
    "staff_name": "Adam",
    "role": "D",
    "staff_id": 8,
    "status": "C",
    "workbase": "Workbase 2"
},
{
    "user_id": 68,
    "service_user": "Philippa",
    "staff_name": "Adam",
    "role": "C",
    "staff_id": 9,
    "status": "C",
    "workbase": "Workbase 2"
},
{
    "user_id": 57,
    "service_user": "Philip",
    "staff_name": "Adam",
    "role": "W",
    "staff_id": 9,
    "status": "C",
    "workbase": "Workbase 2"
}
```

The strucutre D3 is expecting is following,

```
{
    "name":"flare",
    "children":[
        {
            "name":"analytics",
            "children":[
                {
                    "name":"cluster",
                    "children":[
                        {
                            "name":"AgglomerativeCluster",
                            "size":3938
                        },
                        {
                            "name":"CommunityStructure",
                            "size":3812
                        },
                        {
                            "name":"HierarchicalCluster",
                            "size":6714
                        },
                        {
                            "name":"MergeEdge",
                            "size":743
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name":"graph",
                    "children":[
                        {
                            "name":"BetweennessCentrality",
                            "size":3534
                        },
                        {
                            "name":"LinkDistance",
                            "size":5731
                        },
                        {
                            "name":"MaxFlowMinCut",
                            "size":7840
                        },
                        {
                            "name":"ShortestPaths",
                            "size":5914
                        },
                        {
                            "name":"SpanningTree",
                            "size":3416
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name":"optimization",
                    "children":[
                        {
                            "name":"AspectRatioBanker",
                            "size":7074
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

So I need to use the received data to produce a new structure which is basically objects with children arrays.

The way the first structure works is that Workbase 1, has 1 child "Abbey", and in turn "Abbey" has 1 child "Phillipa", now it maybe that Workbase 1 appears many times in the returned data, so all it needs pushing into a Workbase 1 specific object.

Workbase 2 is slightly more complex, Workbase 2 has 1 child "Adam" and "Adam" has 4 children "Raymond", "Allison", "Phillipa" and "Phillip".

Theoretically the data should look like this,

```
{
    "name":"Workbase 1",
    "children":[
        {
            "name":"Abbey",
            "children":[
                {
                    "name":"Phillipa"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name":"Workbase 2",
    "children":[
        {
            "name":"Adam",
            "children":[
                {
                    "name":"Raymond"
                },
                {
                    "name":"Allison"
                },
                {
                    "name":"Phillipa"
                },
                {
                    "name":"Phillip"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

So far I am looping through the object and making sure I am only getting unique workbases,

```
original_data.forEach(function(j){
    if(_.indexOf(workbases, j.workbase) < 0) {
        workbases.push(j.workbase);

        data.push({
            name : j.workbase,
            children : []
        });
    }
});
```

From this point I cannot work out to get the correct children and childrens children into the correct workbase, any ideas?

Comment: What part of the data determines what is a child and what is a parent? i.e. the relationship between Abbey and Phillipa, or Adam and Raymond,Allison,Phillipa,Phillip

Comment: Your first and third data samples are not in a valid format. I assume each should be wrapped in an array (square brackets; `[]`)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a nested approach with a hash table for the names.

```js
var data = [{ "user_id": 3, "service_user": "Phillippa", "staff_name": "Abbey", "role": "A", "staff_id": 2, "status": "P", "workbase": "Workbase 1" }, { "user_id": 60, "service_user": "Raymond", "staff_name": "Adam", "role": "D", "staff_id": 8, "status": "C", "workbase": "Workbase 2" }, { "user_id": 63, "service_user": "Alison", "staff_name": "Adam", "role": "D", "staff_id": 8, "status": "C", "workbase": "Workbase 2" }, { "user_id": 68, "service_user": "Philippa", "staff_name": "Adam", "role": "C", "staff_id": 9, "status": "C", "workbase": "Workbase 2" }, { "user_id": 57, "service_user": "Philip", "staff_name": "Adam", "role": "W", "staff_id": 9, "status": "C", "workbase": "Workbase 2" }],
    result = [];

data.forEach(function (a) {
    var check = function (key, target) {
            if (!this[key]) {
                this[key] = { name: key, children: [] };
                target.push(this[key]);
            }
        }.bind(this);

    check(a.workbase, result);
    check(a.staff_name, this[a.workbase].children);
    this[a.staff_name].children.push({ name: a.service_user });
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let sorted = original_data.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  /* check if the workbase is already in the array */
  let wb = acc.find(wb => wb.name === cur.workbase);
  if (wb) {
    /* check if staff by that name is already in this workbase */
    let staff = wb.children.find(staff => staff.name === cur.staff_name);
    if (staff) {
      staff.children.push({name: cur.service_user});
    } else {
      /* if not, instantiate this staff in the array */
      wb.push({
        name: cur.staff_name,
        children: [{name: cur.service_user}]
      });
    }
  } else {
    /* if not, instantiate this workbase in the array */
    acc.push({
      name: cur.workbase,
      children: [
        {
          name: cur.staff_name,
          children: [{name: cur.service_user}]
        }
      ]
    });
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
```